# Square integrable martingale

Tags: martingales, expected-value

Let $Y$ be a square integrable $(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathbb R^+}$ martingale (namely that $E[Y^2_t]<\infty$ for all t) closed by $Y{_\infty}$.

$1)$ Then why do I know that also $E[Y_\infty^2]< \infty$?? Is it a consequence to the square integrability only or also of the fact that is closed by $Y{_\infty}$?

$2)$ Let $X_t=E[X_\infty|\mathcal F_t]$, then if I know that $X_\infty$is in $L^2$, why $X_t$ is a square integrable martingale?

Comment: By "square integrable" do you intend that $\sup_t E[Y_t^2]<\infty$ or merely that $E[Y^2_t]<\infty$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: I've seen a book where they called square-integrable martingales what in other books are martingales bounded in $L^2$. Is this common? Or is the book "wrong" or lack of rigour?

Comment: @JohnDawkins edited

Comment: To me, "square integrable" means that $E[Y_t^2]<\infty$ for each $t$. The stronger notion (bounded $L^2$ norms) is "$L^2 bounded".

Answer (score 1):

If you just assume that $EY_t^{2} <\infty$ for  each $t$ then $Y_t$ need not converge, so you don't have your $Y_{\infty}$. The first part can be approved under the assumption that $\sup_t EY_t^{2} <\infty$. When you say $(Y_t)$ is  closed by $Y_{\infty}$ you probably mean $Y_t=E(Y_{\infty}|\mathcal F_t)$ for  all $t$ with $Y_{\infty}$ square integrable. In that case we automatically get $\sup_t EY_t^{2} <\infty$.

Apply Fatou's Lemma: $EX_{\infty}^{2} \leq \lim \inf EX_t^{2}\leq \sup EX_t^{2} <\infty$.

The second part follows from Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations: $EX_t^{2}=E(E(X_{\infty}|\mathcal F_t)^{2}) \leq EX_{\infty}^{2}$ since $x \to x^{2}$ is a convex function.

Comment: The first part only holds true when $\sup_t \mathbb E[X_t^2]<\infty$, which is not true for an arbitrary square integrable martingale (we only have that $\mathbb E[X_t^2]<\infty$ for all $t$). Consider $X_t$ as standard Brownian motion - then $\mathbb E[X_t^2] = t<\infty$ for all $t$, but clearly $\sup_t \mathbb E[X_t^2]=+\infty$.

Comment: I believe we have to use the fact that $Y_t$ is closed by $Y_\infty$, that is, $\mathbb E[|Y_\infty|]<\infty$ and $Y_t = \mathbb E[Y_\infty\mid \mathcal F_t]$ for all $t$.

Comment: @Math1000 exactly, I don't know if $supE[X_t]<\infty$

Comment: @Alias__ If you just assume that $EX_t^{2} <\infty$ for  all $t$ then the martingale need not converge and there is no $Y_{\infty}$. So the question does not make sense.  I think square in integrable martingales are supposed to satisfy the condition $\sup X_t^{2} <\infty$.

Comment: @Math1000 Please read my revised answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That is what I meant, precisely. Thank you.